# http://localhost:9090/[object%20Object] 400 error on on D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm experimenting on the design of my website but i can't seem to show my line chart in the div#container of the bootstrap because it keeps showing me the error:

> T http://localhost:9090/[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object] 400

At first it worked on a CSV file but i need it to be a JSON file since the query result of my Java Spring is a JSON value so i converted the CSV file to JSON but suddenly the program didn't work. It only says that error.

Please refer to my code below:

```
var jsonData =
  [
    {
      date: "20-Jul-2019",
      A: 10,
      B: 20,
      C: 16
    },
    {
      date: "21-Jul-2019",
      A: 11,
      B: 22,
      C: 18
    },
    {
      date: "22-Jul-2019",
      A: 13,
      B: 19,
      C: 21
    },
    {
      date: "23-Jul-2019",
      A: 11,
      B: 17,
      C: 22
    },
    {
      date: "24-Jul-2019",
      A: 15,
      B: 16,
      C: 20
    },
    {
      date: "25-Jul-2019",
      A: 16,
      B: 19,
      C: 18
    },
    {
      date: "26-Jul-2019",
      A: 19,
      B: 21,
      C: 18
    },
    {
      date: "27-Jul-2019",
      A: 22,
      B: 25,
      C: 15
    },
    {
      date: "28-Jul-2019",
      A: 18,
      B: 24,
      C: 12
    },
    {
      date: "29-Jul-2019",
      A: 14,
      B: 20,
      C: 16
    },
    {
      date: "30-Jul-2019",
      A: 14,
      B: 18,
      C: 18
    },
    {
      date: "31-Jul-2019",
      A: 16,
      B: 18,
      C: 21
    },
    {
      date: "01-Aug-2019",
      A: 15,
      B: 20,
      C: 22
    },
    {
      date: "02-Aug-2019",
      A: 14,
      B: 21,
      C: 19
    }
  ];

const width = 960;
const height = 500;
const margin = 5;
const padding = 5;
const adj = 30;
// appending SVG first
const svg = d3.select("div#lineChart").append("svg")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "-"
    + adj + " -"
    + adj + " "
    + (width + adj * 3) + " "
    + (height + adj * 3))
  .style("padding", padding)
  .style("margin", margin)
  .classed("svg-content", true);

//-----------------------------DATA-----------------------------//
const timeConv = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%Y");
const dataset = d3.json(jsonData);
dataset.then(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  var slices = data.columns.slice(1).map(function (id) {
    return {
      id: id,
      values: data.map(function (d) {
        return {
          date: timeConv(d.date),
          measurement: +d[id]
        };
      })
    };
  });

  //----------------------------SCALES----------------------------//
  const xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
  xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return timeConv(d.date)
  }));
  yScale.domain([(0), d3.max(slices, function (c) {
    return d3.max(c.values, function (d) {
      return d.measurement + 4;
    });
  })
  ]);

  //-----------------------------AXES-----------------------------//
  const yaxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .ticks((slices[0].values).length)
    .scale(yScale);

  const xaxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1))
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d'))
    .scale(xScale);

  //----------------------------LINES-----------------------------//
  const line = d3.line()
    .x(function (d) { return xScale(d.date); })
    .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.measurement); });

  let id = 0;
  const ids = function () {
    return "line-" + id++;
  }

  //---------------------------TOOLTIP----------------------------//


  //-------------------------2. DRAWING---------------------------//
  //-----------------------------AXES-----------------------------//
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xaxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(yaxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

  //----------------------------LINES-----------------------------//
  const lines = svg.selectAll("lines")
    .data(slices)
    .enter()
    .append("g");

  lines.append("path")
    .attr("class", ids)
    .attr("d", function (d) { return line(d.values); });

  lines.append("text")
    .attr("class", "serie_label")
    .datum(function (d) {
      return {
        id: d.id,
        value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
      };
    })
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
      return "translate(" + (xScale(d.value.date) + 10)
        + "," + (yScale(d.value.measurement) + 5) + ")";
    })
    .attr("x", 5)
    .text(function (d) { return ("Serie ") + d.id; });

  //---------------------------POINTS-----------------------------// 

  //---------------------------EVENTS-----------------------------// 

});
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an error, but a console log.

Comment: But it won't load the data and it's a 400 error.

Comment: Where in your code does the error occur?

Comment: The part where i call the JSON file.

Comment: What file do you want to get? You have inline data, and are passing that data to d3.json which expects a string to load a file (your data, which is not a string, is coerced to a string: "[Object object]", which is where your error is coming from.

Comment: Thanks i fixed it by creating a JSON file. Only the problem is that the code slice is giving me the error. Seems like it only works for CSV files.

Comment: The columns property is only added when parsing CSV/TSV/delimited formats, as the structure has rows (each datum)  and columns (properties), json isn't necessarily structured this way.